# How do i set up tables in an mysql database based on member positions?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to set up tables in a mysql database so that a member can be assigned a position based on their section, group and role.

So if i had a form with three drop down boxes in html like so:

```
<form>
   <select name="section"></select>
   <select name="group"></select>
   <select name="role"></select>
   <button name="setPosition">Set Position</button>
</form>
```

How do I set up the sql tables so that each drop down can show whats available from there respective table based on the previous selection, and how would the member be assigned to that position in the database?

Thanks,

Edit: Sorry from not being clear, I know how to use ajax to get query's from a database and populate the selects with that data. What I need is the sql tables to be set up so that the selects can be context based, so for example, If I select a value from 'section' the 'group' shows all the groups in that section, which it gets from said table.

Comment: 2 very broad questions, have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Sorry from not being clear, I know how to use ajax to get query's from a database and populate the selects with that data. What I need is the sql tables to be set up so that the selects can be context based, so for example, If I select a value from 'section' the 'group' shows all the groups in that section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to set this up would be like this, with a `members` table that holds the id's for the other related tables, it's called "normalizing" the data.

```
table name     columns
--------------------------------------------------
members       section_id, group_id, role_id
sections      id, section_name
groups        id, group_name
roles         id, role_name
```